# Send only one automated email message on any error

Tags: excel, vba

I have code for doing several tasks and would like to receive an email notification on any error. My current code works fine but I have noticed that sometimes I get 2 or 3 messages. Why it is happening so and how to fix it?

```
Sub PerformAll()

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

            Call RefreshQuery
            Call FormatAllCells
            Call BuildListWithClass

            Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

    If Err <> 0 Then
            Dim objOutlook As Object
            Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

            ' CREATE EMAIL OBJECT.
            Dim objEmail As Object
            Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

            With objEmail
                .To = "me.you@company.com"
                .Subject = "There was an error with Importer"
                .Body = "Hello Sir, there was an error with Importer. Please take a look!"
                .Send
            End With

            ' CLEAR.
            Set objEmail = Nothing
            Set objOutlook = Nothing
    End If

    Resume Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like removing `Resume Next` did the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like removing `Resume Next` did the job

Current code:

```
Sub PerformAll()

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

            Call RefreshQuery
            Call FormatAllCells
            Call BuildListWithClass

            Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

    If Err <> 0 Then
            Dim objOutlook As Object
            Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

            ' CREATE EMAIL OBJECT.
            Dim objEmail As Object
            Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

            With objEmail
                .To = "me.you@company.com"
                .Subject = "There was an error with Importer"
                .Body = "Hello Sir, there was an error with Importer. Please take a look!"
                .Send
            End With

            ' CLEAR.
            Set objEmail = Nothing
            Set objOutlook = Nothing
    End If

End Sub
```